# Jenkins use Parameterized Trigger Plugin to build other project with confirmation

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have three project of my Jenkins, A, B and C. When I fill the parameter on A and build it, will send email to me to run B. B only have one choice parameter for confirmation, it must be confirm manually, if B choice parameter is true, C will use A parameter to run some script, if B choice parameter is false, no other action will do of three project and send email to me. How can I achieve this scenario?

This scenario look like:

If true:

A (input parameter when build) → B confirm manually (ture) → C (use A parameter to do something)

If false:

A (input parameter when build) → B confirm manually (false) → will send email to me and not build C

Thanks

Comment: Hi Kelvin, could you show us the code you have for those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I think there are several of ways :) I would do something like this:

If I understand you correctly, going from A to B is done manually, so you are not asking about that.

As for going from B to C.
You should have B job receive this boolean parameter. Then B should have something like that in its Jenkins file:

```
        if (params.MY_FLAG && params.MY_FLAG.toBoolean()){
                                        c_job = build(job: 'C-Job', propagate: true, wait: true)            
        } else {
// Sending you an email . 
}
```